# Grails + spring-security-core:2.0-RC4 + spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2

Tags: grails, spring-security-ldap

I'm using Grails 2.4 + spring-security-core:2.0-RC4.

I want to use LDAP for authentication but allow only usernames that are in the database and enabled for login.

I already have three domains: user, role and UserRole.

I add compile ":spring-security-ldap:2.0-RC2" in BuildConfig.groovy
and followed the example below but It doesn't work:

This is the error I am getting:

> Error | 2015-03-25 18:05:38,542 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] ERROR authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user. Message: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E9, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1 –
>   https://chlebik.wordpress.com/2014/10/27/ldap-authentication-and-db-authorisation-with-grails-spring-security/

How do I resolve this?

Comment: does not work? post the error if you are getting any?

Comment: Error |
2015-03-25 18:05:38,542 [http-bio-8090-exec-2] ERROR authentication.RequestHolderAuthenticationFilter  - An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.
Message: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E9, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1

Comment: Message: Uncategorized exception occured during LDAP processing; nested exception is javax.naming.NamingException: [LDAP: error code 1 - 000004DC: LdapErr: DSID-0C0906E9, comment: In order to perform this operation a successful bind must be completed on the connection., data 0, v1db1; remaining name 'dc=myCompany,dc=org'